Filter: Besides returning the column I want, it also returns the column with the condition, which I do not want
I have successfully extracted data from Column A based on a condition in column D. But Sheets returns column D as well where the conditions has been met. I don't need column D. It interferes.
That's my function: =Filter(Addresses!A2:K600,Addresses!D2:D600=1). All I want are the values in column A, not have Column D repeated

The first argument should be the column(s) you need i.e. A2:A600.

=filter(Addresses!A2:A600,--(Addresses!D2:D600 = 1))

Should only filter on the values you actually want.

Filter Data Without Filter Column

You started your post letting one to believe that you wanted to filter your data excluding the filter column. If that's the case, you could do the following.

Readable and Maintainable
=LET(data,Addresses!A2:G6,filter_column,4,criterion,1,
    c,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),
    s,FILTER(c,c<>filter_column),
    f,CHOOSECOLS(data,filter_column)=criterion,
    r,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,s),f),
    r)

Alternatively, you could use s,TOROW(IFS(c<>filter_column,c),2),.
Compact
(After Removing the Redundant s, f and r Variables)
=LET(data,Addresses!A2:G6,filter_column,4,criterion,1,
    c,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),
    FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,FILTER(c,c<>filter_column)),
        CHOOSECOLS(data,filter_column)=criterion))

LAMBDA function

With a few simple changes (first line and trailing parentheses), you could create a LAMDBA formula...
 =LAMBDA(data,filter_column,criterion,LET(
     c,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),
     FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,FILTER(c,c<>filter_column)),
         CHOOSECOLS(data,filter_column)=criterion)))

... to use it in the Name Manager to create your own LAMBDA function and e.g. name it FilterNFC.

Then you could use it as any other Excel function anywhere in the workbook:
 =FilterNFC(Addresses!A2:G6,4,1)




Google Sheets

Here's a link to Filter No Filter Column on my Google Drive.
I got it to work by slipping in an ARRAYFORMULA for the f variable.

=LET(data,Addresses!A2:G6,filter_column,4,criterion,1,
    c,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),
    s,FILTER(c,c<>filter_column),
    f,ARRAYFORMULA(CHOOSECOLS(data,filter_column)=criterion),
    r,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,s),f),
    r)


It didn't let me break the resulting line.

=LET(data,Addresses!A2:G6,filter_column,4,criterion,1,
    c,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),
    FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,FILTER(c,c<>filter_column)),ARRAYFORMULA(CHOOSECOLS(data,filter_column)=criterion)))


I will certainly give this a try...
